# JavaScript file is not loading fully in all browsers

Tags: javascript, web-applications, browser, load, websphere

I see this strange behavior (or may be I am missing something).
I have WebSphere 8.5. Deployed a EAR. Its working fine.

Instead of repacking and deploying every time for small change, I just copy the js and CSS files directly to the Websphere exploded folder and overwrite the existing files. I see the changes are getting reflected.

I just updated a JS file and added a couple jQuery functions and copied the file like above. Now when I refresh the page, I see the updated code (which is somewhere in the middle of the file). however the js file is not loading fully in all 3 browsers (IE8, Chrome and FF latest). It's getting cut off in the last 10 lines are so.

The file has 1784 lines. Not sure if there is a size limit on the browser side or WebSphere is tinkering with it or something else is going on. Any idea?

I did check the js file I copied to Exploded WebSphere folder. It has complete code.

Note that the page has a few more JS files (jQuery and other files) in addition to this one.

**Edit:**

I think WebSphere is keeping the size of the file somewhere (maybe?) and sending only that size every time, unless there is clean deploy or restart (?).

I removed a few lines of updated code. Now the browser loads, exactly that many number of additional lines of code. Once I remove my code completely, it loads the full file. (This is not an issue with the code though).

Is there a caching that I need to clear in WebSphere?

Comment: Without code we are only able to suggest things, we can not give you any answers.

Comment: Do you mean, you want to go through the huge file?

Comment: Yes, that's the only solution, just add it to github, jsfiddle or something. Without code we can't help.

Comment: I am sure, going through the code wouldn't help. Because, its not the issue with the code itself. Its something to do with the cache, browser settings, or server. Also, pls check my Edit.

Comment: Have you tried restarting your server? Maybe that "solves" it and would indicated that it is a problem with your cache. Alternatively, you could maybe turn off caching, I don't know if that's possible with WebSphere.

Comment: I used to do the same with Tomcat. I did not see this problem. Note that, the change is getting reflected on the client side. But server is keeping the size somewhere. So its kind of weird.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60988/discussion-between-szenc-and-kevin-rave).

Comment: Did you try to click ctrl+F5, it should request reloading of the whole page? The other way could be to try to restart just the application, and see if it works?

Comment: @Gas I tried ctrl+f5. No go. Restarting the server, as expected, did work. But not sure why it shows the updated content (without restarting), but cuts off the text of size greater than the original size. it seems weird to me.

Comment: @SZenC sorry I couldn't land on chat window. Its blocked in my network.

Comment: How about restarting the just the app, not the server?

Comment: @Gas need to try it. Do you have any idea the command to use to restart just the app, on top of your head? I use `stopServer <servernmae>` and `startServer <servername>` from terminal. Not sure if one exist for restarting app itself

Comment: Do you have standalone server or connected to Eclipse? If you have stand alone, it will be easier via web console `http://host:9060/ibm/console  then Enterprise application > select app and Stop/Start. You would need to write jython/jacl wsadmin script to do it from command line. It can be done, but a bit longer task

Comment: Also once you are in console, check if application reloading is enabled for your app. You can test it also changing some jsp file and see, if that is picked up automatically

Comment: I am doing it from Web console anyways. Its not tied to RAD/RSA. But restarting the application does seem to work. While this seems to be a workaround, its still not clear why it cuts off the text.

Comment: @KevinRave, I suggested you ask this question over at Server Fault, maybe someone over there can help you further. And it might be an idea to get your code checked at CodeReview, just to be sure. But maybe Gus can help you out. I don't have any further ideas, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Check this page it [Hot deployment and dynamic reloading](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.base.iseries.doc/ae/trun_app_hotupgrade.html). In general it says that you may need to restart the application.

Also check, if application reloading is enabled, however I'm not sure if it is relevant for static files.

> If reloading of classes is enabled and the polling interval is greater
>   than zero (0), the application files are reloaded after the
>   application is updated. For JavaServer Pages (JSP) files in a web
>   module, a web container reloads JSP files only when the IBM extension
>   `jspReloadingEnabled` in the `jspAttributes` of the `ibm-web-ext.xml` file
>   is set to true. You can set `jspReloadingEnabled` to true when editing
>   your web module's extended deployment descriptors in an assembly tool.

You can restart app from console as provided in comments or via wsadmin script.